# Bot state messed up. Dialog not working as expected. [SDK V3]

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using SDK V3 version 3.15.3. In my bot I am simulating a conversation flow using Dialogs. But instead of hitting the call back function mentioned in context.wait(), after hitting Message.Controller the control is going to StartAsync function in my root dialog and as a result the whole dialog flow is restarting from the beginning rather than proceeding to the function mentioned in the callback for context.wait(). This behavior is also quite random as in few cases ( specially when debugging locally) the bot is acting as expected.

I have tried downgrading to version 3.13, but even that does not work

These are the registration I am doing in Application_Start()

var store = new InMemoryDataStore();

```
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
                   builder =>
                   {
                       builder.Register(c => store)
                                 .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                                 .AsSelf()
                                 .SingleInstance();

                       builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
                                  CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
                                  .ETagBasedConsistency))
                                  .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                                  .AsSelf()
                                  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

                       builder.RegisterType<Dialogs.RootDialog>()
                       .AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                   });
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Expected :
Bot  : Do you want to raise a ticket [State 0]
User : Yes
Bot : State corresponding to ticket details [State 1]

Actual Result :
After State 0 when user types Yes, StartAsync gets called , In Start Async I am doint context.wait(State 0) , so it goes to state 0 again

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest V3 sdk: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.20.1

Comment: Are you still having issues after upgrading to the latest v3 sdk?